# What is a linear projection?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be irreducible smooth projective variety of dimension $n$ over field $k$. What is mean by a finite linear projection 
$$X\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^n_k.$$

Does it mean it is simply a morphism given by a very ample line bundle.

What are linear projections from 
$$\mathbb{P}^n_k\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^n_k$$. Are these morphisms given by sections of $O(1)$.?

Comment: This is sort of a homogeneous version of Noetherian normalization. The first example is projection from a point: pick a point $P \in \mathbb P^n$ and a hyperplane $H$ not containing the point. You take any $Q \neq P$, look at the line through $P$ and $Q$, and see where it hits $H$. This gives you $\mathbb P^n - P \to H$. This is all spelled out in Harris' _Algebraic Geometry_, although not in the language of linear systems.

Comment: @Hoot, thanks. But I want to know if it is given by linear polynomials and linear system.

Comment: Well in some sense all maps are given by linear systems. Once you understand the geometry the linear system bit is not so bad — at the very least I think Hartshorne spells this out for projection from a point: you can pick coordinates so that $P =(1,0\dots)$ and $H = (x_0=0)$. Then projection is the rational map associated to the incomplete linear system spanned by $x_1, \dots, x_n$. It really is just "forget some coordinates". Another interesting thing about Harris' book is that he takes your question as the _definition_ of dimension, so I think it's worth a look.

Comment: @Hoot, ah I see. I am wondering what the significance of linear is in terms line bundles. Whether it's it given in terms of linear homogeneous polynomials